# Python: Split string into multiple lines using delimiter

Tags: python, split

I want to split a string column in Python and keep the repeat data for other columns. Could anyone please suggest on this?

Input:

```
100 name1  a=1,b=2 place1
```

Output:

```
100 name1  a=1 place1
100 name1  b=2 place1
```

Comment: Can you please show your code attempt at this?

Comment: do you always split the third column?

Comment: Yes, need to split only 3rd column

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it differently. My approach was:

1. First split the input string by `whitespaces` and you will get a list
2. Split the 3rd element of the list by `,` and get another list.
3. within a loop, each time make a new copy of the splitted input and append to another list.
4. Modify 3rd element every inner list items of the bigger lists
5. Print them as needed

You can look at the below code:

```
inp="100 name1  a=1,b=2 place1"


splitedWords = inp.split()
result= splitedWords[2].split(",")
lst=[]
for i in range(len(result)):
    lst.append(splitedWords[:])

for i in lst:
    i[2] = result.pop(0)
    print " ".join(i)
```

Output:

```
100 name1 a=1 place1
100 name1 b=2 place1
```